# Cocoa delegate nstabviewcontroller

Tags: swift, cocoa

I have a main `NSTabViewController` with few tabs:

```
class MainTabViewController: NSTabViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do view setup here.
    }

    override func tabView(_ tabView: NSTabView, didSelect tabViewItem: NSTabViewItem?) {
        print(tabView)// returns <NSTabView: 0x101e17a10> but what to do with it ?
    }

}
```

I want to check in every `NSViewController` if variable `hasChanges` is `true` then pop up message:

> "You have unsaved changes. Do you want to change tab ?"

If i check this in `MainTabViewController` i get `<NSTabView: 0x101e17a10>` and what to do with it i don't know.

If i try to use `NSTabViewDelegate` in my `MyViewController` then i don't know how to delegate `MainTabViewController` in it. Where attach it ?

```
class MyViewController: HIDNSViewController {
    func tabView(_ tabView: NSTabView, didSelect tabViewItem: NSTabViewItem?) {
        //Never called
    }
}
```

Comment: I have added a little more to my answer. To clarify it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`0x101e17a10` is the address of the `NSTabView` instance pointed to by the tabView object. You need to print the tabView **identifiers** within your didSelect method.

You need to set the identifiers in the Interface Builder:

[image]

And then (for example):

```
override func tabView(_ tabView: NSTabView, didSelect tabViewItem: NSTabViewItem?) {
    if tabView.selectedTabViewItem?.identifier! as! String == "1" {
        print("FIRST VC")
    } else {
        print("SECOND VC")
    }
}
```

Output when tabbing:

[image]

Comment: i forget to add delegate:)